# count value like progression geometric c#

Tags: c#, numbers

below is my code:

```
if (ClassID == 1)
                awardGot = 1;
            else if (ClassID == 2)
                awardGot = 3;
            else if (ClassID == 3)
                awardGot = 7;
            else if (ClassID == 4)
                awardGot = 15;
            else if (ClassID == 5)
                awardGot = 31;
            else if (ClassID == 6)
                awardGot = 63;
            else if (ClassID == 7)
                awardGot = 127;
            else if (ClassID == 8)
                awardGot = 255;
```

If you realize, is the number multiplied * 2 + 1, but i need a solution to do it automatically, please :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula you're looking for is `awardGot = (1 << ClassID) - 1`, which is 2^ClassID - 1.

For future reference, you can find formulas for integer patterns by using [OEIS](https://oeis.org/).

```
public function canGetAward(step:int) : Boolean
  {
     return (awardGot >> step & 1) == 0;
  }
```

i think it's works, but see the code above, is the receiver from c# to actionscript, and is the same with "<<" in c#, its make sense, thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you're looking for is:

```
awardGot = (1 << ClassID) - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method - I've added it *just because LINQ is cool*.

```
awardGot = Enumerable.Range(0, ClassID).Aggregate(1, (a, _) => a * 2) - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

> is the number multiplied * 2 + 1

Looking at the values it is actually *ClassId^2 - 1* (using `^` for exponentiation).

Thus

```
awardGot = Math.Pow(2, ClassID) - 1;
```

should do it.

Comment: "(1 << ClassID) - 1" works, your code not, but thank you anyway ^_^

Comment: @Rotem - Assuming that `awardGot` is an `int` then this does not work as well. This produces a `double`.

Comment: @Enigmativity My bad, I remembered there being an `int` overload.